Is 必要と判断すれば set phrase?
For context, レジス is an artificial intelligence unit that have rights to control capsules injected in 非ヒト霊長類.
I am unsure with this part:

いずれにせよレジスが必要と判断すれば清香とくるみ以外の全ての非ヒト霊長類の致死カプセルが作動する

I initially thought レジスが必要 is a quotation for 判断すれば. Now I think it makes more sense to regard 必要と判断すれば is a set expression meaning something like "when it is necessary." Is that right? I found few more examples for this usage in massif.la.

(Source: she is beautiful ch. 48)


レジス is the subject of 判断する, not the content of the judgement.
This type of と doesn't even have to be regarded as a "quote". AをB(だ)と + verb is a basic verb usage pattern, although in your case, the Aを part has been omitted. See this answer for similar verbs. 必要と判断する is not something you would memorize as a "set phrase".


レジスが(それを)必要と判断すれば...
if レジス decides it is necessary...

